# Has Crystal got static methods?

Tags: module, static-methods, crystal-lang

Is it possible to do static methods in modules as in Ruby ?

```
module Test
    self.def test
        puts "test"
    end
end
Test::test
```

I get a `expecting token 'EOF', not 'end'` if the call is in the same file ( as shown in the exemple ) and a `expecting token 'CONST', not 'test'` if I place the call in a different file.

What am I doig wrong ? Is there static methods in modules in Crystal ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax for class methods is `def self.test`, not `self.def test`. Class methods are called using `Test.test`, not `Test::test`.